# If I unlock a mutex in reverse order of locking them, is this susceptible to a deadlock?

Tags: c++, multithreading

```
foo() {
mutex_A.lock()
....
mutex_B.lock()

mutex_B.unlock()
mutex_A.unlock()

}
```

So the above is the psudo code that I wrote for my logic. Is it flawed?

Answer (score 4):

No, there is no possibility of a deadlock just from this code.

A deadlock is when two threads (or things) are waiting for each other. Unlocking a mutex doesn't wait for anything, so it can't cause a deadlock.

Comment: I think he was asking if calling this function from multiple threads could cause a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

unlocking doesn't produce deadlock.

Important is order of lock, following might produce deadlock (each wait lock mutex locked by other function).

```
void problematic_foo() {
    mutex_A.lock()
    mutex_B.lock()

    mutex_B.unlock()
    mutex_A.unlock()
}

void problematic_bar() {
    mutex_B.lock()
    mutex_A.lock()

    mutex_A.unlock()
    mutex_B.unlock()
}
```

Note that in c++11, you might lock several mutexes at "once" with [`std::lock`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock):

```
void foo() {
    std::lock(mutex_A, mutex_B);

    mutex_A.unlock()
    mutex_B.unlock()
}
```